# GNOME Activities does not show all files during search

Tags: files, gnome-shell, 20.04, search, activities-overview

The GNOME Shell *Activities* does not search all directories and searches only within recent files.

Language: English (United States)
Formats: España = Spain
Input sources: Spanish

Trying to change my format to English US won't fix it btw.

This has not been fixed in the final release of Ubuntu 20.04, even after applying every update.

Comment: @abu-bua Changing from "recent files" to specific actually causes loss of information. Specific doesn't mean anything *specifically* when it's not expanded, whereas "recent" has a meaning in this context.